# A question regarding determining internal resistance of a cell by using a potentiometer

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, batteries

[image]
In the given figure at null point J current does not flow through JD and AC but current does flow in the second circuit CDEF and primary circuit.My question is why doesn't current flow through ACFED as it gets a path through the resistor.

Comment: You might get an answer here, but I'd have thought [electronics.se], our electronics stack might have been more suited to this type o question.

Answer (score 0):

At balance th there is no current between node $J$ and node $D$ so there can be no potential difference between node $J$ and node $D$.
Now suppose there was a current from node $A$ to node $B$.
This means that charges flow from node $A$ to node $B$ and into the loop $CDEFC$ and then what happens to those charges as they do not escape from node $C$ to node $J$?
They cannot be stored in loop $CDEFC$ thus there cannot be a current from node $A$ to node $B$ which in turn means that the potential difference between node $J$ and node $D$ is zero.
So the potential difference between nodes $A$ and $J$ is equal to the potential difference between nodes $C$ and $D$.